# Create a GitHub task list issue which automatically lists issues with a specific tag

Tags: github, github-actions, github-issues

I've googled this and read the GH documentation and can't see anything. I'm guessing it can't be done automatically but can probably be done with an action (which I have very limited experience with).

I would like to have an issue which automatically populates [a task list](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-task-lists) with any issues which are tagged with a given label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) for this.

To get a list of all issues in a repo that have a specific label, something like this would work:

```bash
label='mylabel'
gh issue list --label "$label" --json number --jq 'map("- #\(.number)")[]'
```

This produces something like

```markdown
- #232
- #150
```

which is unfurled into the full issue titles.

To update an issue, you can use

```bash
issuenum=100
gh issue edit "$issuenum" --body-file file.md
```

where `file.md` contains what you want in the description of the issue.

To use the output of the first command directly, you can use `-` as the input file:

```bash
label='mylabel'
issuenum=100

gh issue list --label "$label" --json number --jq 'map("- #\(.number)")[]' \
    | gh issue edit "$issuenum" --body-file -
```

And all of this can be done as part of a GitHub Actions workflow. For example, with a manual trigger, expecting the label and the issue to update as inputs:

```yaml
name: Update issue with task list for label

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      issue:
        description: Number of the issue to update
        required: true
        type: number
      label:
        description: Label to build list for
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  buildlist:
    name: Build task list
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Get issues and update list
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          label: ${{ github.event.inputs.label }}
          issuenum: ${{ github.event.inputs.issue }}
        run: |
          gh issue list --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY --label "$label" \
              --json number --jq 'map("- #\(.number)")[]' \
              | gh issue edit "$issuenum" \
                  --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" --body-file -
```